# The bottom part of site logo for localized SO is obscured on user profile page when not logged

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, localization

E.g. [my own profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/) page on ruSO.

When not logged (just open on private mode):

> [image: non logged]

All is good when logged:

> [image: logged]

All localized SO are affected.

Related report on ruSO.Meta: [Ползёт и перекрывается логотип](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8827/176217)